# Laravel Carbon DiffForHumans Option (Years, Months, Days)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have read through [the documentation of `DiffForHumans`](https://laraveldaily.com/post/carbon-diffforhumans-parameters-and-extra-options) and it's very straightforward, but is there a way to customize the date to print out:

- 13 Years, 1 Month, 10 Days
- 01 Year, 11 Months, 01 Day

where it will respect the Year/Years, Month/Months, Day/Days?

- Approach 1:

  ```
  $date = Carbon::parse('2010-08-29');
  $formattedDate = $date->diffForHumans(['parts' => 3, 'join' => ', '];
  ```

  Will print out `13 years, 1 month, 4 weeks ago`
- Approach 2:

  ```
  $date = Carbon::parse('2010-08-29');
  $formattedDate = $date->diff(now())->format('%y Year, %m Months and %d Days')
  ```

  Will print out `13 Year, 1 Months and 28 Days`
- Approach 3 (Backup option):

  ```
  $date = Carbon::parse('2010-08-29');
  $formattedDate = $date->diff(now())->format('%y Year(s), %m Month(s) and %d Day(s)')
  ```

  Will print out `13 Year(s), 1 Month(s) and 28 Day(s)`

Is there a vanilla PHP class that could accomplish something similar?

---

### Modified Accepted Solution:

```
public function customDiffForHumans(Carbon $date) : string
    {
        $diff = $date->diff(now());

        $years  = $diff->y ? $diff->y . ' Year' . ($diff->y > 1 ? 's' : '') : '0 Years';
        $months = $diff->m ? $diff->m . ' Month' . ($diff->m > 1 ? 's' : '') : '0 Months';
        $days   = $diff->d ? $diff->d . ' Day' . ($diff->d > 1 ? 's' : '') : '0 Days';

        return implode(', ', array_filter([$years, $months, $days]));
    }
```

Comment: PHP's native DateTime - which Carbon is an extension of to begin with - also has a `diff` method, so you can implement your approach 2 & 3 using that directly, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the custom function for handling same problem:

```
function customDiffForHumans(DateTime $date) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $diff = $date->diff($now);

    $years = $diff->y ? $diff->y . ' Year' . ($diff->y > 1 ? 's' : '') : null;
    $months = $diff->m ? $diff->m . ' Month' . ($diff->m > 1 ? 's' : '') : null;
    $days = $diff->d ? $diff->d . ' Day' . ($diff->d > 1 ? 's' : '') : null;

    return implode(', ', array_filter([$years, $months, $days]));
}

$date = new DateTime('2010-08-29');
return customDiffForHumans($date);
```

Comment: I used this solution but modified it to answer the question, check the question for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this example:

```
Carbon::parse('07-09-2014')->locale('en')->diffForHumans(
    [
        'parts' => 3,
        'join' => ', ',
        'skip' => 'week',
        'syntax' => Carbon::DIFF_ABSOLUTE,
    ]
)
```

Expected output:

```
"9 years, 1 month, 20 days"
```

But yes, this example will not cover leading zero and StudlyCase (you could use [headline](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/strings#method-str-headline)) issues

Answer (score 1):

You can skip unit(s) you don't want:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2010-08-29');
$formattedDate = $date->diffForHumans([
    'parts' => 3,
    'join' => true,
    'skip' => 'week',
]);
```

Side note: `'join' => true` automatically use `,`-`and` (and translate it if you select another language)